# Is Acer Aspire Recovery equivalent to External Flashing?

Tags: laptop, bios, acer-aspire, firmware, flashing

Is the Acer Aspire Recovery method (Fn+Esc) equivalent to externally flashing the BIOS?

What I am asking is that for example if the BIOS were write protected you could not flash it via a software tool from Windows,Linux or even DOS flasher (like Flashit.exe)

However the AA Recovery method copies the entire .fd raw image to the chip in my assuption, so it is able to reflash the BIOS even on a write protected firmware.

Is this the case? Is the Recovery equivalent to extrernal reprogramming, since it copies the entire .fd image file to the BIOS chip.

Comment: @Facebook no, in this context "Recovery" means reflashing the BIOS from the boot block.

Comment: Let me re-read the entire question... one sec

Comment: Please include the make and model specifics and maybe your current BIOS version number. You misspelled "assuption" too so just to a simple [edit] to add and fix the typo. I need to read on the technology of each make and model and this functionality.

Comment: @Facebook i'd rather not... i think it's too much personal information to post here. However I believe I have already found the answer. I think the answer is yes,it updates the entire chip except the boot block itself which has to be updated separately.

Comment: So you looked in the manual and read about the functionality and confirmed what exactly it does which you are talking about or what? The version of your BIOS and the make and model of your Acer laptop is not personal one bit. It's the same for many other devices as well too.

Answer (score 0):

No, a standard "recovery" image will only re-install the operating system as pre-configured by the manufacturer.

**The BIOS will not be flashed at the same time.**

Comment: No, this is BIOS recovery not OS recovery. There is a built in feature in Acer Laptops that reflashes the BIOS from a .fd file which is the raw BIOS format for Insyde BIOS. I believe it copies the entire .fd file to the BIOS chip. What I am not sure about is that it overwrites it entirely or not, or in otherwords does it replace entirely the existing image there or not.